# counting elements and using the count

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have this source:

`<blockquote><p> word1<lat:sup/> word2<lat:sup/> word3<lat:sup/> </p></blockquote>`

desired output:

`<blockquote><p>word1<sup>1</sup> word2<sup>2</sup> word3<sup>3</sup></p></blockquote>`

How can I do that?
of course, in the real source, there can be many more `<lat:sup/>` 's .
There may be more than one `<p>` within the `<blockquote>`, but I need to count the lat:sup's within the blockquote, ignoring the p.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`xsl:number`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#number).

Here's an example (removed the `lat:` prefix for simplicity)

**XML Input**

```
<blockquote>
    <p> word1<sup/> word2<sup/> word3<sup/> </p>
    <p> wordA<sup/> wordB<sup/> wordC<sup/> </p>
</blockquote>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="sup">
        <sup>
            <xsl:number from="blockquote" level="any"/>
        </sup>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<blockquote>
   <p> word1<sup>1</sup> word2<sup>2</sup> word3<sup>3</sup>
   </p>
   <p> wordA<sup>4</sup> wordB<sup>5</sup> wordC<sup>6</sup>
   </p>
</blockquote>
```